# Powerpoint Action Settings

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

In a PowerPoint presentation, how do I make an object (say a rectangle or a circle) to disappear when I click on it?
I have more than one such objects in my presentation and I have a picture behind each of these. So, when I click an object, that object must disappear and the photo behind that should be displayed. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not accomplished with Action Settings. You can do this through an animation effect.

Open the Custom Animation task pane

Select the picture

Click on "Add Effect" --> "Exit" --> "More Effects" and choose an effect. If you simply want it to go away, there is an effect called "Disappear". Click "OK"

Find that effect in the Animation Pane. When the animation is selected, there is a drop down on the right. In the drop down list choose "Effect Options"

Go to the "Timing" tab

At the bottom choose "Triggers"

Select "Start Effect on Click of" and choose the picture you want in the drop down list.

When you click on the picture in the show, it will disappear.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are going to click the objects in a specific order, you can just tell the slide to make each object disappear sequentially upon each click. (I'm not sure if there is a way to do this . . . I barely use PowerPoint.)